# How to remove data gaps in HighCharts xAxis on a scatter chart

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, highcharts, scatter

Currently my graph detects my values and displays unnecesary values that the graph automatically creates. The values need to be a minimum of 0 to a max of 59. So if I have a **100** this number should not be higher than **159** when displaying.
[Here's an example of how the graph looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfUM7.png)

```js
 xAxis: {
            labels: {
                format: '{value}'
                },
          }
```

I guess a very specifict question would be: How do I alterate the **'{value}'** property.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oxo8re2f/1/ Here's the graph

Comment: Trying to get rid of the 580 gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you are looking for broken axis.  This will allow you to get rid of your xAxis gap (the gap at 580).

http://jsfiddle.net/oxo8re2f/3/

You have to include the broken-axis module:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/broken-axis.js"></script>
```

and then define where you want the breaks to be.  In this case:

```
 xAxis: {
            breaks: [{
                from: 565,
                to: 600,
                breakSize: 1
            }],
```

You might have to pre-process your data to find where the breaks are if your data is variable.  For example, you could add a break anytime there is more than a difference of 10 between two points

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter) function to manipulate what gets displayed in the `xAxis.labels` section. A generic format would something like:

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            var label = this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);

            // Use thousands separator for four-digit numbers too
            if (/^[0-9]{4}$/.test(label)) {
                return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
            }
            return label;
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: I tried taht before but I need to change the value parameters. Here's the graph for better understanding. http://jsfiddle.net/oxo8re2f/1/